# Can a "Reducer" in Redux return an initial state by default AND a default value?

Tags: javascript, redux

I am learning Redux at school, as such we are using tests to insure we have benchmarks passing to help us in our understanding of the building blocks.

I am up to the portion where I am creating the `Reducer`function and I am almost done `\o/` however I can't get one test to pass.

> 1) returns the initial state by default

And below the console spits back...

> Reducer returns the initial state by default:
>
> AssertionError: expected undefined to be an object
>         at Context. (tests/redux.spec.js:103:49)

My thinking it's because the test handles some of the concerns one would be responsible for e.g importing, creating action types etc. But not all. So maybe I am missing something the test is not providing?

Anyway here is my reducer file:

```
import pet from "../components/PetPreview";
import { createStore } from "redux";

import { adoptPet, previewPet, addNewDog, addNewCat } from "./action-creators";
// ACTION TYPES
const PREVIEW_PET = "PREVIEW_PET";
const ADOPT_PET = "ADOPT_PET";
const ADD_NEW_DOG = "ADD_NEW_DOG";
const ADD_NEW_CAT = "ADD_NEW_CAT";


// INTITIAL STATE
const initialState = {
  dogs: [
    {
      name: "Taylor",
      imgUrl: "src/img/taylor.png"
    },
    {
      name: "Reggie",
      imgUrl: "src/img/reggie.png"
    },
    {
      name: "Pandora",
      imgUrl: "src/img/pandora.png"
    }
  ],
  cats: [
    {
      name: "Earl",
      imgUrl: "src/img/earl.png"
    },
    {
      name: "Winnie",
      imgUrl: "src/img/winnie.png"
    },
    {
      name: "Fellini",
      imgUrl: "src/img/fellini.png"
    }
  ]
// These dogs and cats are on our intial state,
// but there are a few more things we need!
};


export default function reducer(prevState = initialState, action) {
  var newState = Object.assign({}, prevState)

  console.log('initialState', typeof initialState)
  switch (action.type) {

    case PREVIEW_PET:
      // console.log('newState', newState)
      return Object.assign({}, prevState, {
        petToPreview: action.pet
      });
      break
    case ADOPT_PET:
      return Object.assign({}, prevState, {
        petToAdopt: action.pet
      });
      break
    case ADD_NEW_DOG:
      // console.log('action', action.dog)
      // console.log('prevState.dogs', prevState.dogs)
      newState.dogs = prevState.dogs.concat([action.dog])
      return newState;
      break
    case ADD_NEW_CAT:
      // console.log('action', action.dog)
      // console.log('prevState.dogs', prevState.dogs)
      newState.cats = prevState.cats.concat([action.cat])
      return newState;
      break;
    default:
      return prevState;

  }
  return initialState
}
```

As you can see after the `switch` block I am returning the `initialState`
Shouldn't that be it?

Below is the `redux.spec.js` file:

```
import { expect } from "chai";
import { createStore } from "redux";

// You will write these functions
import {
  previewPet,
  adoptPet,
  addNewDog,
  addNewCat
} from "../src/store/action-creators";
import reducer from "../src/store/reducer";

const DOGS = [
  {
    name: "Taylor",
    imgUrl: "src/img/taylor.png"
  },
  {
    name: "Reggie",
    imgUrl: "src/img/reggie.png"
  },
  {
    name: "Pandora",
    imgUrl: "src/img/pandora.png"
  }
];

const CATS = [
  {
    name: "Earl",
    imgUrl: "src/img/earl.png"
  },
  {
    name: "Winnie",
    imgUrl: "src/img/winnie.png"
  },
  {
    name: "Fellini",
    imgUrl: "src/img/fellini.png"
  }
];

function getRandomPet(pets) {
  return pets[Math.floor(Math.random() * pets.length)];
}

describe("Action creators", () => {
  describe("previewPet", () => {
    it("returns properly formatted action", () => {
      const pet = getRandomPet(DOGS);

      expect(previewPet(pet)).to.be.deep.equal({
        type: "PREVIEW_PET",
        pet: pet
      });
    });
  });

  describe("adoptPet", () => {
    it("returns properly formatted action", () => {
      const pet = getRandomPet(DOGS);

      expect(adoptPet(pet)).to.be.deep.equal({
        type: "ADOPT_PET",
        pet: pet
      });
    });
  });

  describe("addNewDog", () => {
    it("returns properly formatted action", () => {
      const pet = getRandomPet(DOGS);

      expect(addNewDog(pet)).to.be.deep.equal({
        type: "ADD_NEW_DOG",
        dog: pet
      });
    });
  });

  describe("addNewCat", () => {
    it("returns properly formatted action", () => {
      const pet = getRandomPet(CATS);

      expect(addNewCat(pet)).to.be.deep.equal({
        type: "ADD_NEW_CAT",
        cat: pet
      });
    });
  });
}); // end Action creators

describe("Reducer", () => {
  let store;

  beforeEach("Create the store", () => {
    // creates a store (for testing) using your (real) reducer
    store = createStore(reducer);
  });

  it("returns the initial state by default", () => {
    // In addition to dogs and cats, we need two more fields
    expect(store.getState().petToPreview).to.be.an("object");
    expect(store.getState().petToAdopt).to.be.an("object");
  });

  describe("reduces on PREVIEW_PET action", () => {
    it("sets the action's pet as the petToPreview on state (without mutating the previous state)", () => {
      const prevState = store.getState();

      const pet = getRandomPet(DOGS);
      const action = {
        type: "PREVIEW_PET",
        pet: pet
      };
      store.dispatch(action);

      const newState = store.getState();

      // ensures the state is updated properly - deep equality compares the values of two objects' key-value pairs
      expect(store.getState().petToPreview).to.be.deep.equal(pet);
      // ensures we didn't mutate anything - regular equality compares the location of the object in memory
      expect(newState.petToPreview).to.not.be.equal(prevState.petToPreview);
    });
  });

  describe("reduces on ADOPT_PET action", () => {
    it("sets the action's pet as the petToAdopt on state (without mutating the previous state)", () => {
      const prevState = store.getState();

      const pet = getRandomPet(DOGS);
      const action = {
        type: "ADOPT_PET",
        pet: pet
      };
      store.dispatch(action);

      const newState = store.getState();

      expect(newState.petToAdopt).to.be.deep.equal(pet);
      expect(newState.petToAdopt).to.not.be.equal(prevState.petToAdopt);
    });
  });

  describe("reduces on ADD_NEW_DOG action", () => {
    it("adds the new dog to the dogs array (without mutating the previous state)", () => {
      const prevState = store.getState();

      const pet = getRandomPet(DOGS);
      const action = {
        type: "ADD_NEW_DOG",
        dog: pet
      };
      store.dispatch(action);

      const newState = store.getState();

      expect(newState.dogs.length).to.be.equal(prevState.dogs.length + 1);
      expect(newState.dogs[newState.dogs.length - 1]).to.be.deep.equal(pet);
      expect(newState.dogs).to.not.be.equal(prevState.dogs);
    });
  });

  describe("reduces on ADD_NEW_CAT action", () => {
    it("adds the new cat to the cats array (without mutating the previous state)", () => {
      const prevState = store.getState();

      const pet = getRandomPet(CATS);
      const action = {
        type: "ADD_NEW_CAT",
        cat: pet
      };
      store.dispatch(action);

      const newState = store.getState();

      expect(newState.cats.length).to.be.equal(prevState.cats.length + 1);
      expect(newState.cats[newState.cats.length - 1]).to.be.deep.equal(pet);
      expect(newState.cats).to.not.be.equal(prevState.cats);
    });
  });

  describe("handles unrecognized actions", () => {
    it("returns the previous state", () => {
      const prevState = store.getState();

      const action = {
        type: "NOT_A_THING"
      };
      store.dispatch(action);

      const newState = store.getState();

      // these should be the same object in memory AND have equivalent key-value pairs
      expect(prevState).to.be.an("object");
      expect(newState).to.be.an("object");
      expect(newState).to.be.equal(prevState);
      expect(newState).to.be.deep.equal(prevState);
    });
  });
}); // end Reducer
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey, i could not understand the exact issue, do u want to return the initial state by default?, if yes what is happening, can you explain further

Comment: @mindaJalaj What is happening there seems to be one last test which is not passing. Essentially `returns the initial state by default` is not passing.

Comment: I think @jaihindhreddy has answered the question beautifully, is it working?

Comment: Honestly I haven't tried it. I did read through it, and some of the conclusions were incorrect (the newState variable is needed—albeit in my present code). I guess I would have rather had someone help with my code and not do a rewrite. There was some great insight AND I DO APPRECIATE the hand, but seemed like it was a exercise in razzle dazzle and not in teaching. Like there is not a lot of explaining and teaching which is a sign of a good answer to a question IMHO. Also using words like 'glaringly obvious' and 'clutter' seemed a bit much,

Comment: That being said I did 'upvote' it. Hey just because I don't get it, doesn't mean someone else might not think it's gold....

Comment: Okay, got your point.I have a question ,What is the expected output for default test case, can you print the expected output as well?

Comment: In the spec it says `1) returns the initial state by default` and this is the error...
`1) Reducer returns the initial state by default:
     AssertionError: expected undefined to be an object`

Comment: is it mention, what is the initial state, how should it look?

Comment: also try to return PrevState instead of intialState after switch block ends, as in the last test case - it expects previous state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the test cases, one of the test case default says

```
it("returns the initial state by default", () => {
    // In addition to dogs and cats, we need two more fields
    expect(store.getState().petToPreview).to.be.an("object");
    expect(store.getState().petToAdopt).to.be.an("object");
  });
```

meaning there must be petTpPreview and petToAdapt protery attached to the store at the inital itself. this can be done by adding these two as boject to the state as follows.

```
// INTITIAL STATE
const initialState = {
  petToPreview:{},
  petToAdopt: {},
  dogs: [
    {
      name: "Taylor",
      imgUrl: "src/img/taylor.png"
    },
    {
      name: "Reggie",
      imgUrl: "src/img/reggie.png"
    },
    {
      name: "Pandora",
      imgUrl: "src/img/pandora.png"
    }
  ],
  cats: [
    {
      name: "Earl",
      imgUrl: "src/img/earl.png"
    },
    {
      name: "Winnie",
      imgUrl: "src/img/winnie.png"
    },
    {
      name: "Fellini",
      imgUrl: "src/img/fellini.png"
    }
  ]
// These dogs and cats are on our intial state,
// but there are a few more things we need!
};
```

hope it helps!

Comment: That was it my friend! Can't believe it was so simple! It Actually it SAYS as much `// These dogs and cats are on our intial state,
// but there are a few more things we need!` right there as a hint!
Also I think it was the mental transition of saving state like you do as per normal in React vs saving state in Redux, like you just demonstrated! THANK YOU!

Comment: You're welcome. Hope you liked the answer, and things are clear.

Comment: Indeed! Crystal!

Answer (score 1):

All paths in the switch statement lead to a `return`, which means your `return initialState` on the penultimate line is unreachable.
Also, your `newState` is nothing but a clone of `prevState`, and is unnecessary.
Removing that, and adding a helper function for switchcase combined with some es6 spread love, your code becomes

```
const switchcase = cases => defaultValue => key =>
  (key in cases ? cases[key] : defaultValue);
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) =>
  switchcase({
    [PREVIEW_PET]: { ...state, petToPreview: action.pet },
    [ADOPT_PET]: { ...state, petToAdopt: action.pet },
    [ADD_NEW_DOG]: { ...state, dogs: [...state.dogs, action.dog] },
    [ADD_NEW_CAT]: { ...state, cats: [...state.cats, action.cat] },
  })(state)(action.type);
```

With all the clutter gone, it's glaringly obvious that the problem is in the fact that your code returns the `initialState` object if `action.type === undefined`. And your `initialState` object contains only `dogs` and `cats` properties, whereas your test expects there to be `petToPreview` and `petToAdopt` properties.

You can add those properties in the `initialState` or you can change the test depending on what functionality you want.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you return the previous state by default? The by default is the case that the reducer doesn't care about the action, and simply return its current state, which is prevState in your case.